# How can I only show form if user hasn't already filled it in?

Tags: php, sql, forms, laravel, if-statement

I am working with Laravel5.2. Currently when a user logs in they are taken to a page, at this page is a form which must be displayed. I want to make it so only if the form hasn't already been filled in then for it to show.

My table structure is as shown:

```
User                       Questions
--------------------------------------------
id                            id
name                          q1
email                         q2
password                      q3
                              user_id
```

I have managed to make it so when the user posts the form their user ID gets posted to it also but I don't quite know how to make a check for this to be displayed or not.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::post('home', function () {
    $userq = new App\Userregq();
    $userq->Q1 = Input::Get('Q1');
    $userq->Q2 = Input::Get('Q2');
    $userq->Q3 = Input::Get('Q3');
    $userq->user_id = Auth::user()->id; 
    $userq->save(); 
    return redirect('level1');
});
```

And here is my **form:**

```
    <P> Please fill in this questionairre before you start if you have already done just click the next arrow:</p>
    <div id="form_container">

    {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'home'))!!}
     {!!Form::label('Q1','Why have you decided to use this application?')!!}
            {!!Form::textarea('Q1')!!}<br><br>
            {!!Form::label('Q2','What three things would you like to get out of this application?')!!}
            {!!Form::textarea('Q2')!!}<br><br>
            {!!Form::label('Q3','What time constraints do you foresee and how can you plan around them?')!!}
            {!!Form::textarea('Q3')!!}<br><br>
        <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "{{Auth::user()->id}}">

            {!!Form::submit('Submit')!!}
        {!! Form::close() 

!!}
```

**UPDATE**

I have added this to my **HomeController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

    $showForm = ! App\Userregq()->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)->exists();
        //return view('home');
return view('form-view', compact('showForm')); 
    }

}
```

And this is my updated form:

```
@if($showForm)
<div id="form_container">

{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'home'))!!}
 {!!Form::label('Q1','Why have you decided to use this application?')!!}
        {!!Form::textarea('Q1')!!}<br><br>
        {!!Form::label('Q2','What three things would you like to get out of this application?')!!}
        {!!Form::textarea('Q2')!!}<br><br>
        {!!Form::label('Q3','What time constraints do you foresee and how can you plan around them?')!!}
        {!!Form::textarea('Q3')!!}<br><br>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "{{Auth::user()->id}}">

        {!!Form::submit('Submit')!!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a new column to the table e.g `questionairre_filled` which is a boolean. So if the user has answered all questions set the `questionairre_filled` to 1/true and then use a middleware to check this.

If it failes the middleware is redirecting to the page with the Questionairre form.

The Middleware would looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class QuestionairreMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->questionairre_filled) {
            redirect to the form page
        }

        // If true redirect to the page without the forms
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried other suggested methods and they have not worked so I am going to give this a go. Would this also be the same as before that when the form is submitted to send a hidden input to the boolean attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about how your model relationships work, the simplest solution is to just check whether the current user id already exists in the table. Personally, I prefer to put this information in the controller and load it as a variable. Here's one example:

```
// controller
$showForm = ! App\Userregq::whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)->exists();
return view('form-view', compact('showForm'));

// form
@if ($showForm)
    // show the form here
@endif
```

Note that this is just an example. You may need to check whether the user is logged in, you may want to do it through model relationships, etc.

Comment: I have tried to put it in my controller and load it as a variable and I have tried it just using the if but cannot seem to get it to work?

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried? The concept is sound so there's probably just something small in your code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hmm, that looks correct. Do you get some error, or just no error and the form is displayed?

Comment: I get this error `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\App\Userregq()` Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: You have to 'use' this class Userregq in your controller.

Comment: `public function Userregq()
 {
  $showForm = ! App\Userregq()->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)->exists();
  return view('form-view', compact('showForm')); 
 }`

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek, didn't notice my mistake. If you get any namespace errors, you can just do `\App\Userreqg`, `\Auth` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the relation with Userregq in the User model, the check if there is a record in the Question table from the controller.

**User Model:**

```
Class User extends Model{
    // ...

    public function userregq(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Userregq');
    }

}
```

**HomeController:**

```
Class HomeController extends Controller{

    public function index(){
        if (!Auth::user()->userregq){
            // User didn't answer to the questions
        }
        else{
            // User answered to the questions
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have already defined this relationship in my user model like:
` 
public function userq()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Userregq');
    }
}
`

Comment: What would go in the if else where you have commented?

Comment: So in the first section I would put the normal page layout and in the second I would add the form code?

Comment: the opposite, in the first you put the form, and in the "else" the normal home

Comment: I managed to do that but now i am getting this error?
`Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found`

Comment: I have fixed all my error but cannot get it to work. I created a new view for if it was completed and this is what the if statement looks like.
```
 public function index()
    {
  if (!Auth::user()->userregq){
   return view('home');
  }
  else{
   return view('completed');
  }
       ```